# Linked api Integration

Tags: linkedin-api

Hi friends I am using LinkedIn API to integrate LinkedIn profile and messages to my website.

I got one sample example throgh googling. But the output is coming in XML output.

Then, how can I bind all those things to my website controls?

Comment: What programming language are you using? What platform and framework? Without this information, any answer would be a guess.

Comment: i am using Asp.net 2.0 with c#

Comment: I am interested in your code, as I have yet to find anything that works how I want it to. Eg with out using the Callback or redirect functions in the API. Essentially I want todo one webrequest to get my authication token and then another to perform my query in linked in.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer java script API of linkedin

for more details visit Linkeidn javaScript api docs =>
 [Java Script API](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1223)

Answer (score 0):

You get XML output from LinkedIn such as XMLFile.xml.

Following example shows output in label.

```
DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();

tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml"));

lblUser.Text = tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["first-name"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linkedin api urls, by default you get an XML response. You can add `?format=json` at the end or the url to get response in json format instead of XML.

e.g.

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~
```

will give XML result while

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json
```

will give json result.

Hope it helps.